# How to add support Views Infinite Scroll to Background Images module?

Tags: media, views

I try to add support Views Infinite Scroll to [Background Images](https://www.drupal.org/project/bg_image) module.

It has function [bg_image_add_background_image()](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/bg_image/tree/bg_image.module#n289) that makes classes (with URLs to background images) for all visible rows on Views block (use Infinite Scroll pager). Also `bg_image_add_background_image()` function put that classes to `head` on HTML document.

I think I need alter `bg_image_add_background_image()` function and add listener like `jQuery(selector).on("DOMNodeInserted", ..., function(){...});` to that section of code:

```
 // Add the css if we have everything we need.
  if ($selector && $image_path) {
    $style = "$selector {";
    $style .= "background-color: $bg_color $important;";
    $style .= "background-image: url('$image_path') $important;";
    $style .= "background-repeat: $repeat $important;";
    $style .= "background-attachment: $attachment $important;";
    $style .= "background-position: $bg_x $bg_y $important;";
    $style .= $bg_size;
    $style .= $background_size_ie8 ? $ie_bg_size : '';
    $style .= variable_get('bg_image_extra_css', '');
    $style .= "}";
    drupal_add_css($style, array('type' => 'inline', 'media' => $media_query, 'group' => CSS_THEME));
    return TRUE;
  }
  else {
    return FALSE;
  }
```

But I don't know how!.. Help me, if you can, please.

Comment: Before you start, be aware that mutation events such as `DOMNodeInserted` are now deprecated, and won't be available in browsers for much longer. If this needs to work for a year, you're on the right track. If it needs to work beyond that, you're going to have to find a more robust solution

Comment: What ``jQuery().on(...)`` event would make that functionality?

Comment: Don't know off the top of my head - you want to ask that on Stack Overflow though, not here, it's a JS-specific question

Comment: Ok, I understood. If I still want to do through ``DOMNodeInserted`` how to do that on ``bg_image_add_background_image()``?!

Comment: Yep. I found best solution for this — http://stackoverflow.com/a/12597182/5334651 And now.. how to add this to ``bg_image_add_background_image()`` function? Help.