# How to call function from PHP file (or another module) in JS file from my custom module?

Tags: javascript

After [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/177984/how-to-add-support-views-infinite-scroll-to-background-images-module) question, I try to write custom module to add support Views Infinite Scroll to Background Images module. Here is my code:

**my_module.module**

```
/**
 * @file
 * Module file for Background Image for Views Infinite Scroll.
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_page_build().
 */

function my_module_page_build() {
  // Settings.
  drupal_add_js(array(
    'viewClass' => '.view-content',
    'nodeClass' => '.node-content',
  ), 'setting');
  // Add JS to page.
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/js/my_module.js');
}

/**
 * My function.
 */

function my_module_function() {
   // Code here
}
```

And **./js/my_module.js**

```
/**
 * @file
 * This is main script of Background Image for Views Infinite Scroll.
 */

(function($, Drupal) {

  Drupal.behaviors.my_module = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $(Drupal.settings.viewClass).on('DOMNodeInserted', function() {
        // Code here
      });
    }
  }

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

How call function `my_module_function()` in my JS file?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a menu callback in your module, that will be used by JS to send-receive values from PHP.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function my_module_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['my-module/my-function'] = array(
    'title' => 'Ajax callback for my function.',
    'page callback' => 'my_module_function',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

function my_module_function() {
  // Remember you have to print your results if you want to
  // send any values back to JS.
  print 'Hi, there!';
  drupal_exit();
}
```

Now in your JS code, you make an Ajax call and, optionally, get values back from PHP (if desired).

```
$.ajax({
  url: Drupal.settings.basePath + "?q=my-module/my-function",
  done: function(data) {
    // If my_module_function returns any value, it will come in the data variable.
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok, If ``my_module_function`` don't returns any value? I mean, I'm try to alter original function from Background Images module — http://cgit.drupalcode.org/bg_image/tree/bg_image.module#n289

Comment: What function are you trying to run from JS?

Comment: I try to refresh function in ``bg_image`` module (http://cgit.drupalcode.org/bg_image/tree/bg_image.module) that place styles with background images for each node (in row) to ``head`` document when Views Infinite Scroll loaded new row content with background image.